# How to get mac address of connected devices to a raspberry pi access point?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, access-point

I have followed the guide [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) to make the raspberry pi a Wi-Fi access point.

But how can I get MAC address of connected devices?

Answer (score 3):

This command will list all connected devices on the interface `wlan0` with details including the MAC address:

```
sudo iw wlan0 station dump
```

Comment: You don't need `sudo` to run iw for this

Answer (score 3):

This should display the Mac addresses and associated IP addresses.

```
ip neigh show dev wlan0
```